# Recovering a partition with encrypted /home directory in Ubuntu 18..04

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I have about 5 partitions on my Desktop computer, the one I'm using now is 18.04, the one with the encrypted /home directory is older. Theres some important files and data in there so if its possible to recover it, I'll take the time to do it. So first thing I did was check what partitions are in there:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 42.1 MiB, 44183552 bytes, 86296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 14.5 MiB, 15204352 bytes, 29696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004f908

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   62500863   62498816  29.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2        62502910  160157695   97654786  46.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3  *    160157696 1953523711 1793366016 855.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5        62502912  117922805   55419894  26.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       117923840  160157695   42233856  20.1G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

So mounting the partition and taking a look at whats in there, heres what I got:

```
dominic@domscomputer:/mnt/recover$ cd /mnt/recover/home
dominic@domscomputer:/mnt/recover/home$ ls -l
total 28
drwxrwxrwx 19    1005    1005 4096 Apr 23  2017 decodify
drwxrwxrwx  3 dominic dominic 4096 Apr 23  2017 horse
drwxrwxrwx  5    1009    1009 4096 Apr 30  2017 horsebox
drwxrwxrwx  2    1008    1008 4096 Apr 29  2017 jimbob
drwxrwxrwx  2    1007    1007 4096 Apr 29  2017 johnjoe
drwxrwxrwx  2    1006    1006 4096 Apr  8  2017 new_user
drwxrwxrwx  2    1004    1004 4096 Feb 17  2017 sammy
dominic@domscomputer:/mnt/recover/home$ cd /mnt/recover/home/horse
dominic@domscomputer:/mnt/recover/home/horse$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dominic dominic 56 Feb 10  2017 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dominic dominic 52 Feb 10  2017 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

There was a lot of files in the rest of the file system, could they be of any use?

EDIT: Since I didn't have the passwords, it didn't work:

```
/mnt/recover/home/horse$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private -rw /media/sda3/home/.ecryptfs/horse/.Private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/mnt/recover/home/.ecryptfs/horse/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] n
INFO: To recover this directory, you MUST have your original MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: When you first setup your encrypted private directory, you were told to record
INFO: your MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: It should be 32 characters long, consisting of [0-9] and [a-f].

Enter your MOUNT passphrase: 
mount: /tmp/ecryptfs.5GDXtbtp: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
ERROR: Failed to mount private data at [/tmp/ecryptfs.5GDXtbtp].
```

Comment: I don't wanna waste any more time on this. Would it be possible for me to backup the /home directory so I can try and encrypt it another time? I have a bit of an idea of what the password might be so I might be able to do it with hashcat. Also is there any other useful data I can recover from the other directories? I backed up the /var directory cuz it has all my web projects in there.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't use the `-a` flag for `ls` so it didn't list any hidden files, but the ecryptfs-recover-private program found at least one  in `home/.ecryptfs/horse` folder (it contains all the user's encrypted data, `home/horse` is just a mountpoint).

You could definitely just back up the whole home directory and try again later, but you'll definitely need the login passphrase or mount passphrase to decrypt the data, no matter what.

All your user data *should* be in your user home, but there's usually some config files in /etc that might be useful (`/etc/fstab`?).